# Not able to import simpletransformers.ner in python as it says ImportError: cannot import name 'BertweetTokenizer'

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to do bert based NER and trying to import,

```
from simpletransformers.ner import NERModel, NERArgs
```

I have installed simpletranformers in pip and when I try to import,

```
import simpletransformers.ner
```

it says, `ImportError: cannot import name 'BertweetTokenizer'`. When I try to install BertweetTokenizer, it throws

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for BertweetTokenizer
```

Not sure, what I am missing. Kindly help

Comment: Try to get the latest version do pip install --upgrade simpletransformers. Maybe even do this for the transformers package as well.

Comment: `pip install -U simpletransformers transformers` solves in my case.